# vb.net web browser new tab or new window on right click

Tags: vb.net

i have made a web browser in vb.net 2013 and whenever i right click on a link and press new window it takes me to IE new window, i want it to open in my own new window, and plus i want to have a new tab option on right click too thaaaanks in advance, im new at this so anything is ok... this is my code for new tab and window respectively...

```
Public Sub addTab(ByRef tabControl As TabControl)
    Dim browser As New webBrowserFunction
    Dim tab As New TabPage
    browser.Tag = tab
    tab.Tag = browser
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)
    tab.Controls.Add(browser)
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    browser.Navigate(My.Settings.HomePage)
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = tab
End Sub

Private Sub NewWindowToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewWindowToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim newWindow As New frmVortex
    newWindow.Show()
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Webbrowser control doesn't support multiple tabs, but if you want to make new tabs you should use tab control with multiple webbrowser controls, check this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/785637ac-a920-4592-974c-bf9b7ac03b7f/creating-a-multi-tabbed-browser-using-webbrowser-control-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral